# website content and text in one screen android netbeans

Tags: android, text, netbeans, web, screen

I would like to open a website in a new screen but without occupy the complete screen. 
In the screen there should be texto, button(s) and the contente of the website (as inside a window)

This in Android / Netbeans 7.3.1.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

set layout_height  attribute for your WebView correctly according to your need do not let it to fill whole screen